# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 on a single GPT SSD which contains Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, installation, uefi, gpt

I recently bought a brand new 64 bit PC with a (ASUS) motherboard that supports UEFI and a GPT formatted 240Gb SSD, which contains Windows 7 in the first of 3 (80Gb) partitions.
When the system arrived, it booted into Windows 7 like a dream, with no problems.
I did not originally want Windows, but the manufacturer does not work with Linux (of any flavour), so I thought I would install Ubuntu into the second partition and dual boot.
I downloaded the 12.04 64bit version and proceeded to install.
Having selected to 'install', the screen became corrupted, with multicoloured garbage across the middle third of the screen !!
So, I rebooted and --- MISSING OPERATING SYSTEM !!!
The only way I can now get into Windows is via Super Grub2.
First question - what went wrong ?
2nd - Will Ubuntu install on a GPT disk partition ?
3rd - Will it install alongside Windows 7 without screwing the boot mechanism ?
4th - How do I do it ?
I have scoured the internet looking for appropriate answers and found NONE !
Please help.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *What went wrong?* -- it's impossible to say from the information you've provided. It could be a hardware fault (bad RAM, say) that caused the installer to flake out and corrupt everything; or it could be a bug in the installer; or it could be a buggy EFI implementation; or any number of other possibilities. Unless you can find somebody who's had the same problem on the same or a closely-related model, it'll take some effort to debug this problem.
2. *Will Ubuntu install on a GPT disk partition?* -- Yes, at least, assuming there are no bugs in the firmware or hardware problems to block it. I've done numerous Ubuntu installations to GPT disks, under both BIOS and EFI firmware.
3. *Will it install alongside Windows 7?* -- Yes, although boot loader issues can sometimes require tweaking the setup afterward. For instance, on EFI-based systems, GRUB 2 often fails to add an appropriate entry for Windows, which requires adding a new entry manually (or, IMHO better, replacing GRUB 2 with a more reliable boot loader).
4. *How do I do it?* -- I recommend you begin by running some hardware diagnostics. If you find no hardware faults, you'll have to track down the problem with your system, which is likely to be extremely system-specific, and so better suited for solving in a Web forum, Usenet newsgroup, or other more interactive place than this one.